# How to open a separate UI Window from QMainWindow?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

So I have a MainWindow.ui in the class QMainWindow. I also have a separate QWidget and QDialog window (not sure which one is better to use) that I would like to open by using the menu bar from MainWindow.ui. I know that I can simply do something like:

`self.main_layout.addWidget(self.form_widget)`
or
`flashC = flashCard()
 flashC.show()`

But I want to do this in Qt Designer, so that I don't have to change the .py file every time I run pyuic5 (since these changes will be replaced upon running.)

My question is, *how do I make it so that QMainWindow can open other windows that I make later from **within Qt Designer**.* Right now I can't access any other windows in my signal/slot editor.

[image: [See Image]]

I've been trying to figure this out and the books and other resources that I've looked at haven't pointed me in the right direction. I just want to know if it's possible to call other windows from within Qt Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple `QMainWindow` in your application. To create a second window simply define it in Qt Designer as you have for your current window, then import and create an instance of it.

Remember it will only appear once you call `.show()`

Comment: Sorry, how do you import? Does this mean everything has to be done programmatically and I can't just do the Signal/Slot editor for the menu bar to call on other windows?

Comment: As far as I know you would need to do the opening programmatically. The window can be defined entirely within Designer, but you need to create the new window object from Python.